# Selecting in order after many insertions

Tags: mysql

I have two scripts; one of them inserts rows into the database, and the other processes newly entered, so-far-unprocessed rows.

```
CREATE TABLE table (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, col1 VARCHAR(32), col2 VARCHAR(32));
```

So the first script does several separate insert queries:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, col1 ,col2) VALUES (0, 'val1_1', 'val1_2');
INSERT INTO table (id, col1 ,col2) VALUES (0, 'val2_1', 'val2_2');
INSERT INTO table (id, col1 ,col2) VALUES (0, 'val3_1', 'val3_2');
...
```

Then the second script uses something like this to select the unprocessed rows:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > (SELECT MAX(id FROM table_processed)) ORDER BY id LIMIT 1000;
(do some processing)
(for each id processed from table: INSERT INTO table_processed (id) VALUES ({table.id});)
```

Sometimes, the first script will need to insert something like 5000 rows. I noticed that there was at least one instance when the processing script seemed to skip over many of the rows (basically skipped 3000 of them), and was wondering what could cause this and how to prevent it (if it skips over them once, then the next time it'll continue to skip over them since it uses > MAX(id)).

Or is this not supposed to happen? (in which case I guess it'd have to be error with the second script query)

Comment: could it be that you are using the same value for `id` in your insert statement?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say, id is AUTO_INCREMENT so 0 is just dummy.

Comment: if AUTO_INCREMENT, you should leave it off: `INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES ('val3_1', 'val3_2')`.

Comment: If id is AUTO-INCREMENT, why are you explicitly inserting it? And when you say the script skipped over many of the rows, do you mean you have a gap in the id field that runs from, say, 2000 to 5000?

Comment: I'm not, I just included it in the question to make it clear that there's an id column. I double checked and even if it's specified the database will rewrite it so that it automatically increments (and in the actual script it doesn't specify it, but it is the same if it does).

There is no gap in "table", the id correctly goes in sequence. But, in the second script that executes the SELECT statement, it skips over something like rows with id 1000-4000, and only processes the first and last few.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 2 insert transactions are running, and a later transaction (=gets a higher auto_incremented id) is done earlier, those higher auto increment ids are visible earlier to other transactions (i.e: your processing one) then the lower ones (in a not yet committed transaction, or possibly even an rolled back one). Every INSERT gets an id of the global sequence, so those 2 transactions could not even have a single range of id's, but create a sort of striped use of said range. A good way to work is to ***never*** rely on either order or value of auto_incremented ids, do not use them for ***anything*** but an ***identifier***.

The most obvious solutions are:

1. Do not use that MAX(id), but do a LEFT JOIN of table to table_processed, and use those not yet existing in table_processed, but this may be heavy on the selecting side.
2. Let the INSERTs do an exclusive LOCK on the table (undesirable in busy scenarios, you already seem to have multiple concurrent INSERTs).
3. Let the INSERTs be done with a `processed=0` indexed column (possibly this is just the default value, and you can omit it in the insert), and just `SELECT .. FROM table WHERE processed=0`, set to `1` when done.

A simple mistake to make is to say: OK, I'll just COMMIT after every single insert so that transaction is done as soon as possible, which is *still* vulnerable to race conditions, so don't use that.

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful, I'll probably go with the third solution.

Comment: That one was is my favorite too ;)